# Spring Maven: Where to place credential properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, properties

I'm currently developing an application which requires access to an API with credentials. I didn't want to put them hard coded in the application so I created a configuration.properties file for them.

At the moment this file is located in src/main/resources and access it with the following code.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:configuration.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

This means that if I change something in the configuration I need to redeploy the WAR.

**My question** is: Where do I put this configuration file so that I don't need to redeploy in case of a change in the configuration?

*I don't want to put it somewhere random on my computer so that I can share my code with other people without to much trouble with the file's location.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by placing my properties file in Tomcat "D:\Documents\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps"

And Access it with the following property-placeholder

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.base}/conf/configuration.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Comment: well that lacks a bit of comfort. I would not store application configuration inside tomcat/conf - just in case you upgrade tomcat or create another server in eclipse. What you can do is pass the base folder into spring: <context:property-placeholder location="file:${conf.home}/conf/env.properties" /> and pass conf.home as -Dconf.home="/my/path/to/conf" into the application. This way it should be possible to have the file inside the project and pass its path via your IDE into the application (that should avoid having to dig around in eclipse internal folders like wtpwebapps)

Comment: That's the way to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're already close.

I agree its a good way to have one .war file and reuse it everywhere without adopting it to a specific environment. That means you cannot include it in the .war

What I would do is creating configuration zip files with the assembly plugin (if there are multiple variations). For example from /src/main/config/env1

Then use an environment variable to point to that folder.
The property placeholder configurer thing in spring then references that location through that system property instead of the classpath:

these zip files can be used to be deployed with the .war file (via ssh using the ant runner plugin or some other way)

That can also be used for the logging configuration. Spring has a resolver that will even reload the log config if you change it on the file system.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. At the moment I already solved it, but if i hadn't. this would be the way to go! I shall post my answer.